# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not found

Tags: api, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

==============

> **When I run my API automation test I get the below error.  But able to run the test completely without any issue when the cucumber-java
> version is 7.2.3    How do I resolve this issue?
> Note few other details below. Using JDK 11 JRE 1.8**

==============

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

> **Note the Trace and pom.xml below.**

==============

```
    [Trace][1]
```

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module not found
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1219)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1228)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1105)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1089)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1139)
at io.restassured.path.json.mapper.factory.DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.create(DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.java:29)
at io.restassured.path.json.mapper.factory.DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.create(DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.java:27)
at io.restassured.common.mapper.factory.ObjectMapperFactory$create.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.createJackson2ObjectMapper(Jackson2Mapper.groovy:44)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.this$2$createJackson2ObjectMapper(Jackson2Mapper.groovy)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:198)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.serialize(Jackson2Mapper.groovy:50)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.serialize(Jackson2Mapper.groovy)
at io.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper$serialize.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.serializeWithJackson2(ObjectMapping.groovy:217)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:343)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite$StaticMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:153)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:217)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:240)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.serialize(ObjectMapping.groovy:154)
at io.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$serialize.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.body(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:756)

> ```
> **POM.xml**
> ```

```
==========================================================================================================================================================
           <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
          </properties>
        
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.13.2</version>
            <!--  <scope>test</scope> -->
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.4</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
           <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
            </dependency>
             <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
            </dependency> 
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
                <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.4</version>
           <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with "testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:7.3.3'" (gradle).

I changed to "testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:7.0.0'" and when I changed it and ran again test then I got a correct error message about the real problem that was "Unrecognized field 'programId'" (for example) and then I can fix the problem (that was a missing field in my class).

Answer (score -1):

I installed Jackson JDK8 repository in my pom.xml file and it fixed this problem:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8